# My chrome extension iframes my website. So if I add Google Analytics to my website, will my chrome extension get it by default?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I have a webapp and a chrome extension of the same webapp. In popup.html, my extension just iframes my webapp as follows. My question is, if I add Google Analytics in webapp, will my extension automatically have it?

```
<iframe id="messenger" partition="persist:messenger5" height="500px" width="400px" frameborder="0" src="https://myapp.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: No, it won't "have it" - why would it need it?

Comment: So, I will need to manually add it? If it iframes my web app, will it be possible to detect page views etc in extension?

Comment: @JaromandaX we want to track how much users are using extension and how much are using web app separately.

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me, I don't understand what you're attempting to do - perhaps I'll just let someone else come along and answer :p

Comment: @JaromandaX i just wanted to know if i add Google Analytics in my web app, will Chrome extension have it by default then? Will Chrome app also sends the events to Google Analytics i configure it for?

Comment: Oh, your extension may be able to access GA in the iframe - I thought you wanted GA in the extension to magically come from the iframe

Comment: No, I was just curious that whether adding GA to web app would also result page views from extension as extension is just iframing my web app.

Comment: What do you mean by "a chrome extension of the same webapp"? Chrome is dropping support for extension-apps: https://www.theverge.com/2020/1/15/21067907/google-chrome-apps-end-support-lune-windows-macos-linux - how can a webapp run in the browser as an extension? then it isn't a **web** app _because it isn't on the web_. Please provide more technical details about how your extension works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my chrome extension just iframes my webapp and my webapp has Google extension, so my chrome extension also has Google Analytics automatically.